# Swashbukle doesn't show the Odata routes in the Swagger UI

Tags: odata, .net-6.0, webapi

I am using Net6 web api with odata support. I am not using any apicontroller in the code and instead i am inheriting from ODataController and swagger UI is not showing the routes in the UI and event i am not able to browse those endpoints separately. Below is my samplecode

```
public class ValuesController : ODataController
 {
        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 5)]        
        public IQueryable<Note> Get()
        {
            return _context.Notes.AsQueryable();
        }
 }
```

Middleware configuration

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddOData(opt =>
{
    opt.Conventions.Remove(opt.Conventions.OfType<MetadataRoutingConvention>()
        .First());
    opt.AddRouteComponents(GetEdmModel())
    .Select()
    .Expand()
    .Count()
    .Filter()
    .OrderBy().SetMaxTop(100).TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
}).AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("Notes",
    new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Notes API", Version = "v1", });
});
```

Please note I have one controller with same config and it is showing in the swagger UI, if I add new controllers inheriting from ODataController it is not working. any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: Can you share section of middleware that related swagger and odata?

Comment: builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(opt =>
    {
        opt.Conventions.Remove(opt.Conventions.OfType<MetadataRoutingConvention>()
            .First());
        opt.AddRouteComponents(GetEdmModel())
        .Select()
        .Expand()
        .Count()
        .Filter()
        .OrderBy().SetMaxTop(100).TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
    }).AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore); ;

Comment: builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("sample",
    new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "sample API", Version = "v1", });
});

Comment: please can you add it to question.

Comment: added to the question